# Prove that if $f,g:\{0,...,n\}\to\mathbb{R}$ are two strictly increasing functions with the same image then it must be the case that $f=g$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I will use the following definitions in the text below:

For each $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ let's denote the set of all integers greater than or equal to $a$ and less than or equal to $b$ by $[a,b]_\mathbb{Z}$:

> $[a,b]_\mathbb{Z}:=\{z\in\mathbb{Z}|a\leq z \leq b\} =
>  \bigcup_{z=a}^b\{z\}$

Let's denote the set of all natural numbers with $0$ by $\mathbb{N}_0$ :

> $\mathbb{N}_0 := \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$

And let's denote the set of all functions from $[0,n]_\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{R}^{[0,n]_\mathbb{Z}}$:

> $\mathbb{R}^{[0,n]_\mathbb{Z}} := \{f|f:[0,n]_\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}\}$

---

We have to prove the following proposition:

> If $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is some natural number, And if
>   $f,g:[0,n]_\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$ are two strictly increasing functions
>   with the same image, Then it must be the case that $f=g$

Translating it into logic notation we get that we have to prove:

> $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_0,\forall f,g\in\mathbb{R}^{[0,n]_\mathbb{Z}}, \Big(\forall i\in [0,n-1]_\mathbb{Z}, f(i)<f(i+1)\Big)\land\Big(\forall i\in [0,n-1]_\mathbb{Z},g(i)<g(i+1)\Big)\land f([0,n]_\mathbb{Z})=g([0,n]_\mathbb{Z})\longrightarrow \forall i\in [0,n]_\mathbb{Z},f(i) = g(i)$

---

We will prove the proposition by induction on $n$:

---

**BASE STEP:**

For $n = 0\in\mathbb{N_0}$ we have to prove that:

> $\forall f,g\in\mathbb{R}^{\{0\}}, \Big(\forall i\in \emptyset, f(i)<f(i+1)\Big)\land\Big(\forall i\in \emptyset,g(i)<g(i+1)\Big)\land f(\{0\})=g(\{0\})\longrightarrow \forall i\in \{0\},f(i) = g(i)$

(Note: In this case $[0,n]_\mathbb{Z} = [0,0]_\mathbb{Z} = \{0\}$ and $[0,n-1]_\mathbb{Z} = [0,-1]_\mathbb{Z} = \emptyset$)

Let $f,g\in\mathbb{R}^{\{0\}}$, i.e. $f,g:\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$, be some functions that satisfy:

**(1)** $\forall i\in \emptyset, f(i)<f(i+1)$

**(2)** $\forall i\in \emptyset,g(i)<g(i+1)$

**(3)** $f(\{0\})=g(\{0\})$,

(Side note: **(1)** and **(2)** are true by default but we do not need to use any one of them for the proof in this particular case)

We will prove that $\forall i\in \{0\},f(i) = g(i)$:

Since $f(\{0\}) = \{f(0)\}$ and since $g(\{0\})=\{g(0)\}$ we get by **(3)** that $\{f(0)\}=\{g(0)\}$ and so it must be the case that $f(0)=g(0)$ and we can conclude that $\forall i\in\{0\}, f(i)=g(i)$ as was to be shown.

---

**INDUCTION HYPOTHESIS**

Suppose that for some $n = k\in\mathbb{N}_0$ we have

> $\forall f,g\in\mathbb{R}^{[0,k]_\mathbb{Z}}, \Big(\forall i\in [0,k-1]_\mathbb{Z}, f(i)<f(i+1)\Big)\land\Big(\forall i\in [0,k-1]_\mathbb{Z},g(i)<g(i+1)\Big)\land f([0,k]_\mathbb{Z})=g([0,k]_\mathbb{Z})\longrightarrow \forall i\in [0,k]_\mathbb{Z},f(i) = g(i)$

---

**INDUCTIVE STEP**

We must prove that for $n = k+1$ we have:

> $\forall f,g\in\mathbb{R}^{[0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z}}, \Big(\forall i\in [0,k]_\mathbb{Z}, f(i)<f(i+1)\Big)\land\Big(\forall i\in [0,k]_\mathbb{Z},g(i)<g(i+1)\Big)\land f([0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z})=g([0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z})\longrightarrow \forall i\in [0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z},f(i) = g(i)$

Let $f,g\in\mathbb{R}^{[0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z}}$, i.e. $f,g:[0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$, be some functions that satisfy:

**(1)** $\forall i\in [0,k]_\mathbb{Z}, f(i)<f(i+1)$

**(2)** $\forall i\in [0,k]_\mathbb{Z},g(i)<g(i+1)$

**(3)** $f([0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z})=g([0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z}) = A$,

We will prove that $\forall i\in [0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z},f(i) = g(i)$:

By **(1)** we get $\forall i\in [0,k]_\mathbb{Z}, f(i)<f(k+1)$ and thus $\forall i\in [0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z}, f(i)\leq f(k+1)$, Also since $f(k+1)\in f([0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z})$, We can conclude that $f(k+1)=\max f([0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z})= \max (A)$.

Similarly by **(2)** we get $\forall i\in [0,k]_\mathbb{Z}, g(i)<g(k+1)$ and thus $\forall i\in [0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z}, g(i)\leq g(k+1)$, Also since $g(k+1)\in g([0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z})$, We can conclude that $g(k+1)=\max g([0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z}) = \max(A)$.

And we've got that:

**(4)** $f(k+1) = g(k+1)$,

Now let's define two functions $\tilde{f},\tilde{g}\in\mathbb{R}^{[0,k]_\mathbb{Z}}$, i.e. $\tilde{f},\tilde{g}:[0,k]_\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$, As follows:

$\forall i\in [0,k]_\mathbb{Z}, \tilde{f}(i) := f(i)$

And $\forall i\in [0,k]_\mathbb{Z}, \tilde{g}(i) := g(i)$

It is clear from **(1)** and **(2)** that $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ satisfy:

**(5)** $\forall i\in [0,k-1]_\mathbb{Z}, \tilde{f}(i)<\tilde{f}(i+1)$

**(6)** $\forall i\in [0,k-1]_\mathbb{Z}, \tilde{g}(i)<\tilde{g}(i+1)$

Now we'll show that:

**(7)** $\tilde{f}([0,k]_\mathbb{Z}) = \tilde{g}([0,k]_\mathbb{Z})$

As follows:

$\tilde{f}([0,k]_\mathbb{Z}) = \tilde{f}(\bigcup_{i=0}^k\{i\})=\bigcup_{i=0}^k\tilde{f}(\{i\})=\bigcup_{i=0}^k\{\tilde{f}(i)\}=\bigcup_{i=0}^k\{f(i)\}=\bigcup_{i=0}^{k+1}\{f(i)\}\backslash\{f(k+1)\}=\bigcup_{i=0}^{k+1}f(\{i\})\backslash\{f(k+1)\}=f(\bigcup_{i=0}^{k+1}\{i\})\backslash\{f(k+1)\}=f([0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z})\backslash\{f(k+1)\}$

And now by **(3)** and **(4)** we get: $f([0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z})\backslash\{f(k+1)\}=g([0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z})\backslash\{g(k+1)\}=g(\bigcup_{i=0}^{k+1}\{i\})\backslash\{g(k+1)\}=\bigcup_{i=0}^{k+1}g(\{i\})\backslash\{g(k+1)\}=\bigcup_{i=0}^{k+1}\{g(i)\}\backslash\{g(k+1)\}=\bigcup_{i=0}^{k}\{g(i)\}=\bigcup_{i=0}^{k}\{\tilde{g}(i)\}=\bigcup_{i=0}^{k}\tilde{g}(\{i\})=\tilde{g}(\bigcup_{i=0}^{k}\{i\})=\tilde{g}([0,k]_\mathbb{Z})$

Thus by **(5)**, **(6)** and **(7)** we can conclude by using the **INDUCTION HYPOTHESIS** that $\forall i\in [0,k]_\mathbb{Z},\tilde{f}(i) = \tilde{g}(i)$
, But by definition of $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ it implies that $\forall i\in [0,k]_\mathbb{Z},f(i) = g(i)$, And by **(4)** we get $\forall i\in [0,k+1]_\mathbb{Z},f(i) = g(i)$ as was to be shown.

**Q.E.D.**

---

I've proved the proposition and this was the proof I've came up with,
Do you think there is a shorter way to prove the proposition? Is this the standard way to prove the proposition? Thanks you...

Comment: I will never read all that. If $n=-1$ then $f,g$ are empty and therefore equal. Assume that any such functions are equal for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then let $f,g$ be two such functions with domain $\{0,1,...,n+1\}$. Since they are increasing, the maximum of thrie image is $f(n+1)$ and $g(n+1)$, respectively. Since their images are equal we get that $f(n+1)=g(n+1)$. Consider the functions $f|_{\{0,...,n\}}$ and $g|_{\{0,...,n\}}$. They satisfy the same conditions but for the smaller domain. Therefore $|_{\{0,...,n\}}=g|_{\{0,...,n\}}$. Combining these two equalities we get that $f=g$.

Comment: @totoro Thank you, That’s exactly what I’ve done.

Comment: Some advice: mathematics should be in English when possible. Avoid logical symbols like $\forall,\exists,\wedge,\vee$, and do not strive to write everything as a well-formed formula. People can transform conceptual descriptions into logical proofs in their heads.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is so long and so notation packed that I can't read it to see if it's correct. It probably is.

You ask for a shorter proof. 
I would argue this way. If $f \ne g$ then there is a smallest $k$ such that $f(k) \ne g(k)$. We can assume $f(k) < g(k)$. Since $g$ is strictly increasing, $f(k)$ can never be in its image. That contradicts the hypothesis so $f$ must be the same as $g$.

(There is really an induction in disguise here, since I've used the fact that any nonempty set of positive integers has a least element.)

Comment: +1 Nice and concise.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternate proof . . .

Suppose $f\ne g$.

Our goal is to derive a contradiction.

Let $b$ be the least element of $\{0,...,n\}$ such that $f(b)\ne g(b)$.

Without loss of generality, assume $f(b) < g(b)$.

Since $f,g$ have the same range, we get $f(b)=g(a)$, for some $a\in\{0,...,n\}$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&f(b) < g(b)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&g(a) < g(b)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a < b&&\text{[since $g$ is strictly increasing]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f(a) = g(a)&&\text{[by minimality of $b$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f(a) = f(b)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a=b&&\text{[since $f$ is strictly increasing]}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction.